# Get all conflict dates in a rails query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oracle, date, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

everyone!

I'm creating a rails app to manage and schedule vacations in a government institution.

The system has to filter the vacations and load them into a grid (see the grid in the link below, in portuguese, sorry for that).

The problem is: I've got to filter all vacations that are in conflict.

Example: (MM-dd-yyyy)

John's vacation: starts in 01-01-2018, ends 01-15-2018.
Marie's vacation start in 01-01-2018, ends 01-10-2018.

John's vacation and Marie's vacation are in conflict.

A person can split your vacation through the year.

How can i write a rails query to get all vacations that are in conflict?

Vacation's schema:

```
t.integer "fs_manager_id", limit: 19, precision: 19
t.integer "year", precision: 38
t.date "date_ini"
t.date "date_end"
t.integer "days", precision: 38
t.boolean "approved", default: false
t.datetime "date_approved", precision: 6
t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
t.integer "fs_balance_id", precision: 38
t.integer "fs_person_id", precision: 38
t.index ["fs_balance_id"], name: "i_fs_vacations_fs_balance_id"
t.index ["fs_manager_id"], name: "i_fs_vacations_fs_manager_id"
t.index ["fs_person_id"], name: "i_fs_vacations_fs_person_id"
```

[Image: Grid with all vacations and vacation's owner dd/MM/yyyy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fYKRs.png)

EDIT : The problem is: I've got to filter all vacations that are in conflict and show them to user.

Comment: I don't think there is a Query that does exactly what you want. I would start by grouping all the dates and then whatever group of dates has more than 1 value I would assume they intersect.

Comment: Which one database do you use?

Comment: @MikhailKatrin, Oracle !

Comment: Updating: The problem is: I've got to filter all vacations that are in conflict and show them to users in a grid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is how you can do this in `ActiveRecord` version 5 or above, broken up and assembled in a few chunks.  You need to join `vacations` to itself, which I have done with the alias `conflicts`:

```ruby
# Match only on differing ids because each vacation will conflict with itself in the result
conflict_join = Vacation.joins("LEFT JOIN vacations AS conflicts ON conflicts.id != vacations.id")

conflict_by_start_date = conflict_join.where("conflicts.start_date >= vacations.start_date AND conflicts.start_date <= vacations.end_date")
conflict_by_end_date = conflict_join.where("conflicts.end_date >= vacataions.start_date AND conflicts.end_date <= vacations.end_date")

# Can only use the .or function in ActiveRecord 5 or above
conflicts = conflict_by_start_date.or(conflict_by_end_date)
```

The result will be all `vacations` that have another conflicting vacation.  If vacation A conflicts with vacation B, then A and B will be included in the results.  In the case of multiple conflicts, like A conflicts with B and conflicts with C, then A would appear multiple times so you may want to handle that somehow.

This query could also be used to get a result which will show which specific vacations conflict with one another via a `select` like `conflicts.select("vacations.id AS vacation_id, conflicts.id AS conflicting_vacation_id")`

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say how to make such query using ActiveRecord

But you can write a <s>monster</s> simple sql query:

```
query = 'select distinct a1.*
    from vacations as a1, vacations as a2
    where a1.start_date < a2.end_date and
    a1.end_date > a2.start_date and
    a1.id <> a2.id'
response = ApplicationRecord.connection.execute(query)
```

And then manually parse a reponse using `map` or anything like this.

Comment: I tried something like that, but the maintainable was a mess, but can works if used carefully. Thanks a lot.